# Can i add RangetoHTML(rng) and then strbody in the email using VBA?

Tags: vba

I have created a macro that will send emails using the code taken from here https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

I am curious about this part:

```
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
```

My RangetoHTML takes the range from a template in excel and changes for every client. The table is in the email body and can vary in size depending on the client so the last bit of the email which is static will change in its position depending on how big the client is.

Can i modify the .HTMLBody=RangetoHTML(rng) to .HTMLBody=RangetoHTML(rng) & StrBody?

```
 where StrBody = "<br><br> Thank you." & _
            "<br><br><br> <i> Call if you have any questions </i>"
```

Comment: "Can I do xyz" can usually be answered by trial and error :) Next time, please try on your own first, and then ask the more specific question if you have problem(s) with the attempted implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The end of the output from `RangetoHTML` looks like this:

```
....
<!----------------------------->
<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD-->
<!----------------------------->
</body>

</html>
```

If you just append some other HTML fragment, it will be outside of the closing `</body></html>` tags, so it would be better to insert it *inside* the output.

Something like:

```
Dim html
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

    html = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .HTMLBody = Replace(html, "</body>", StrBody & "</body>")
```