# Add text to body, and range to HTMLbody in an email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an email macro on a button in an Excel sheet.

I adapted code I found here to copy a range of cells into the email body which. I want to add text above that.

I can get either the text (.body) or the copied range (.HTMLbody) to show.

```
Sub DESPATCH_LOG_EMAIL()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Sheets("DESPATCH LOG").Range("B1:C8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You have not entered anything to despatch" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "person@person.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Despatch Notification"
        .Body = "Please see items despatched below:
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .display   '.Display brings up email but doesn't auto send it
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

If I remove the ".HTMLBody" then the email contains the text contained in ".Body".

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255359) adds text to the end. Use same principle to add to the beginning ie `.HTMLBody = Replace(RangetoHTML(rng), "<body>", "<body><p>Please see items despatched below:</p>")`

Comment: Oh you absolute beauty!!! Thankyou so much!

I'd like some of that text to be a link to a file stored on a shared drive - you wouldn't know how to do that as well would you? You've helped a vast amount already though, so really, thankyou!!!

Comment: So have a look how a [Hyperlink](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) is created in html.

Comment: You're also missing a " after the .body section to close off the text.